# batch file on Windows for youtube-dl not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, youtube-dl

I'm trying to use this batch file below to process a bunch of YouTube videos.

```
@echo off
echo Starting batch script
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\youtube-dl
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_l9XKOFt6oHtwWWnt_zNg3PX5Wssi4s4Ss" --audio-quality 0
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_kP8cX8DV33AWt9L5QCuwQzWYqae2jMcIo" --audio-quality 0
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_nNJBk4Zdivjgrj54NgPsubqd4VolevUd0" --audio-quality 0
echo all file operations complete
```

`youtube-dl` is located in `cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\youtube-dl`

Each of the 3 `youtube-dl` commands works fine if I paste it individually into the Command Prompt.

However, when I run this batch file (`.bat` extension), I get this error:

> youtube-dl: error: you must provide at least one URL

What can I do to fix this batch file please?

**Update**: I think what's happening is that all 3 `youtube-dl` commands are getting entered at the same time. What can I do so that the 2nd one is only entered after the 1st one has finished processing, and the 3rd one is only entered after the 2nd one has finished processing?

**Update 2**: So upon further investigation it looks like the `%` symbols in my code are not interpreted the same way when executed via the Batch Script. The Batch Script ignores the content between the `%`'s. Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this in a batch file, you need to escape your `%` with another one like this: `%%`. If your commands are using the correct syntax:

```
@echo off

echo Starting batch script
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\youtube-dl
youtube-dl -o "%%(playlist_index)s-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_l9XKOFt6oHtwWWnt_zNg3PX5Wssi4s4Ss" --audio-quality 0
youtube-dl -o "%%(playlist_index)s-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_kP8cX8DV33AWt9L5QCuwQzWYqae2jMcIo" --audio-quality 0
youtube-dl -o "%%(playlist_index)s-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "..\..\FFMPEG" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_nNJBk4Zdivjgrj54NgPsubqd4VolevUd0" --audio-quality 0
echo all file operations complete
```

Further reading: [percent symbols](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html)